# How can I treat my event bindings as logic in Javascript?

Tags: jquery, event-binding

I want to create an event binding only if another event has happened, first, if an user hovers an element, add a class so that its hover state is shown, if the user doesn't click inside of it, simply act like a simple `:hover`, if the user has clicked inside of the tooltip, then don't make the tooltip dissapear, but if the user has, after this first click, clicked outside of the tooltip, make the tooltip dissapear:

```
jQuery('.helper-tooltip').on('mouseenter', function() {
    let current_element = jQuery(this);
    current_element.addClass('open');
});

jQuery('.helper-tooltip').on('mouseleave', function() {
    let current_element = jQuery(this);
    current_element.removeClass('open');
});

jQuery('.tooltip-hidden-video-container').on('click', function() {
    this.innerHTML = '';
    jQuery('.helper-tooltip').off('mouseleave');

    jQuery('body').on('click', function(event) {
        //I'd like to go back on .helper-tooltip and remove the 'open' class if the user has clicked outside of it.
    });
});
```

But here's the interesting part. If I were, on my third `'on('click')` to select any event that can be easily repeated, say, a hover `mouseenter`, **it would execute the logic as many times as I've hovered it.**

How can I treat these event bindings as logic so that my code works as per my requirements? Is this even a good thing?

Comment: Try changing your `jQuery('body').on('click'...` to `jQuery('body').one('click'...` - this ensures it only fires once the next time that event happens

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put the element in a state once it's been clicked then when it attempts to hide, check if it is in that state or not

A simple way would be to use a class like so:

```
jQuery('.helper-tooltip').on('mouseenter', function() {
    let current_element = jQuery(this);
    current_element.addClass('open');
});

jQuery('.helper-tooltip').on('mouseleave', function() {
    let current_element = jQuery(this);

    // Only remove class if element does NOT have the .clicked class
    if(!current_element.hasClass('clicked')){
        current_element.removeClass('open');
    }
});

jQuery('.tooltip-hidden-video-container').on('click', function() {
    this.innerHTML = '';
    let current_element = jQuery(this);
    current_element.addClass('clicked');

    jQuery('body').on('click', function(event) {
        current_element.removeClass('clicked').trigger('mouseleave');
        //I'd like to go back on .helper-tooltip and remove the 'open' class if the user has clicked outside of it.
    });
});
```